# Writing an HttpPost RestResource for multipart contentType

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, post

I've been able to write a simple HttpPost RestResource that would accept a Base64 string as one of the parameters and make an attachment out of it.

But actually we want to use multipart instead of base64 strings. After some googling I found [this blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/09/using-binary-data-with-rest.html) which literally says:

> REST API now supports the MIME multipart content-type standard which allows you to upload large binary files of up to 500Mb

But I also found [some docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm) that say:

> Apex REST currently doesn't support requests of Content-Type multipart/form-data.

Who should I believe? They are both on Salesforce site and both seem to be trustworthy. I've also found a lot of examples how to make an outbound multipart request, but didn't find any examples of inbound ones.

Is there a way(and an example) to write an apex HttpPost method that would accept multipart?

Comment: Just wondering, were u able to find a solution for this, I am confused too

Comment: @manza no, we just went with standard API that does support multipart

Answer (score 3):

The Force.com REST API and Apex REST are not the same thing. The first is provided by the platform to interact with objects and the second is written by a developer in Apex to interact via a custom implementation.

So in short, the platform's [REST API can accept a multipart binary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) but you cannot code your own Apex class exposed as a @RestResource and do the same thing.

From the SFDC [Which API Should I Use?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm) document:

**REST API**

- **What is it for?** Accessing objects in your organization using REST.
- **When to use it?** You want to leverage the REST architecture to integrate with your organization. No WSDL requirement. Well-suited for browser-based applications, mobile apps, and highly-interactive social applications.

**APEX REST**

- **What is it for?** Building your own REST API in Apex. Exposes Apex classes as RESTful Web services.
- **When to use it?** You need to build custom JSON responses or you want to expose custom functionality that you implemented in Apex.